# fabric-ca-client enroll with error Failed to read response of request: POST http://localhost:7054

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I checkout project fabric-samples and run file startFabric.sh to start Fabric blockchain network. 
 After that, I run `node enrollAdmin.js` to enroll the new admin

 Now, I want to use the command line of fabric-ca-client to add a new user to org1. I execute the commands below:

1. Access to ca_peerOrg1 docker
   `docker exec -it ca_peerOrg1 bash`
2. I check the value of 
   `$FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME` is unset 
   `$FABRIC_CA_HOME` is `/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server`
3. Go to `/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server` directory and check command 
   `fabric-ca-client`
   [image]
4. And run this command
   `fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://admin:adminpw@localhost:7054`

    But it occurs error below:

[image]

Anyone could help? Thanks for reading

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered the same problem. For anyone who is interested, this error indicates fabric-ca-server is running with TLS enabled.

To get rid of this error, you need to make the following changes to the `fabric-ca-client` command:

- use https instead of http in the url
- use ca host name instead of localhost in the url
- provide the TLS cert file for the server's listening port via `--tls.certfile`

e.g. `fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://admin:adminpw@ca.org0.example.com:7054 --tls.certfiles /certs/ca/ca.org0.example.com-cert.pem`

The TLS cert file was generated by fabric-ca-server at startup. The default file location is `$FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME/tls-cert.pem`. Otherwise, the location is specified by `$FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE` or `fabric-ca-server-config.yaml`